# Attempting to remove repeated 0 on c program

Tags: c

I have a C program that you introduce a sequency of numbers until you type -1, It works fine with debian compiling with gcc ("$gcc act.c -o act") but now I am on windows 10 with devc++ and TDM-GCC 4.9.2 and the output fails

if you introduce "1 5 6 7 8 0 0 0 0 5 5 6 6 6 6 8 4 1 0 0 0 2 5 0 5 6 8"
the output must be "1 5 6 7 8 0 5 5 6 6 6 6 8 4 1 0 2 5 0 5 6 8"

As I said on linux works, but on windows the output is only the first number in this case 1.

Whats wrong in my code?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int secuencia_numeros;
        int aux_secuencia_numeros = -1; //Utilizamos el -1 como numero auxiliar
        printf("\n\n\t Quitar ceros consecutivos.\n\n");
        printf("Introduce una secuencia de numeros [fin = -1]: ");
        scanf("%d",&secuencia_numeros);
        while(secuencia_numeros != -1) {
                fflush( stdin );
                if((secuencia_numeros ==0)&&(aux_secuencia_numeros == 0)) {
                }else{
                        printf("%d ",secuencia_numeros);
                }
                aux_secuencia_numeros = secuencia_numeros;
                scanf("%d",&secuencia_numeros);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check return of scanf, do not attempt to flush stdin.

Comment: This program works..Don't use fflush

Comment: Yes, it's the `fflush(stdin)` that trips up your Windows exe. (And please consider using more concise variable names. What about `n` and `prev`? A single number isn't a "secuencia", after all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior. That's why avoid using it.

In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior). <sup>1</sup>

1. [Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/)